# CMake Eclipse C++ Hello World easy tutorial - trouble with two projects part

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake

I am working on a tutorial and was making great progress until I got to the hardest part.  The tutorial is [Using CMake: Hello World Example](http://wiki.icub.org/yarpdoc/using_cmake.html).  The last and hardest part is the section for "Building a library and program separately".  I have created the two projects in Eclipse and followed the instructions all the way to the end.  The writer gives a hint that there is still more work to be done to make the CMake build successful.  Meanwhile, I would like to get both projects working with each other in Eclipse.

When I try to build all I receive this error:

```
12:25:45 **** Build of configuration Debug for project Hello ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/hello/Hello.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I"/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer/src/namer" -include"/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer/src/namer/World.h" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/hello/Hello.d" -MT"src/hello/Hello.d" -o "src/hello/Hello.o" "../src/hello/Hello.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/hello/Hello.cpp

Building target: Hello
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++ -L"/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer" -o "Hello"  ./src/hello/Hello.o   -l"/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer/src/namer/World.h"
ld: library not found for -l/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer/src/namer/World.h
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Hello] Error 1

12:25:45 Build Finished (took 161ms)
```

and the Problems are:

```
4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
library not found for -l/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer/src/namer/World.h
make: ***[Hello] Error 1
make: ***[Namer] Error 1
```

When I try to build just the library project (Namer), I receive these errors:

```
12:36:11 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Namer ****
make all 
Building target: Namer
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++  -o "Namer"  ./src/namer/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.o  ./src/namer/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.o  ./src/namer/World.o   
duplicate symbol _main in:
    ./src/namer/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.o
    ./src/namer/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.o
duplicate symbol _info_compiler in:
    ./src/namer/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.o
    ./src/namer/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.o
duplicate symbol _info_platform in:
    ./src/namer/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.o
    ./src/namer/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.o
duplicate symbol _info_arch in:
    ./src/namer/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.o
    ./src/namer/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.o
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Namer] Error 1

12:36:11 Build Finished (took 61ms)
```

and the Problems are:

```
4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
make: ***[Namer] Error 1
```

Is anyone out there up to the task of helping me?  This is supposed to be an easy HelloWorld example where the Hello part comes from the main project and the name comes from the Library project.  It probably is easy for someone who understands configuring multiple C++ projects in Eclipse.  Maybe the CMake is fighting Eclipse, I don't know.

Thank you in advance for your help.

-------------------------------------------- **Source Code** ----------------------------------

OK.  For the Hello project, there is a CMakeLists.txt file and a FindNamer.cmake file.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
find_package(Namer REQUIRED)
include_directories("${Namer_INCLUDE-DIRS}")
add_executable(hello main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello ${Namer_LIBRARIES})
```

**FindNamer.cmake**

```
find_path(Namer_INCLUDE_DIRS World.h /usr/include "$ENV{NAMER_ROOT}")

find_library(Namer_LIBRARIES namer /usr/lib "$ENV{NAMER_ROOT}")

set(Namer_FOUND TRUE)

if (NOT Namer_INCLUDE_DIRS)
    set(Namer_FOUND FALSE)
endif (NOT Namer_INCLUDE_DIRS)

if (NOT Namer_LIBRARIES)
    set(Namer_FOUND FALSE)
endif (NOT Namer_LIBRARIES)
```

And the **Hello.cpp** file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "World.h"

int main() {
  printf("Hello %s\n", getWorld().c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

The Namer project has a **CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)
project(Namer)
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
add_library(namer World.cpp World.h)
```

Here is the **World.cpp**:

```
#include "World.h"

std::string getWorld() { return "Earth"; }
```

Here is the **World.h**:

```
#include <string>

std::string getWorld();
```

Please let me know if there is anything else you need.  Thank you again.

Comment: The  -l"/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer/src/namer/World.h" is wrong as a .h file is for compile only - so you have set up the make files wrongly so we need to see them. Also I think eclipse is trying to link CMakeCCompilerId which also implies yo have the eclipse import wrong and we need to see that.

Comment: Yeah - you need to show your CMakeLists.txt file(s) for us to be able to help you.